# How to store the value of an variable before it gets updated in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am running a loop over a variable to take input from the user.
I am running this loop because, the number of new values I have to take depends upon some previous user input (therefore `for loop`).

So I am looking for a way to store the value of the variable before it gets updated in the next iteration.

Comment: Hi Ujjwal. Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you share a snippet of the code you have tried ? Also let us know what your exact output should be and what you are getting right now. It's hard to answer your question without these!

Comment: use list to append all inputs

Answer (score 1):

```
num_of_values = int(input("Enter total number of values"))
values = []
for value in range(num_of_values):
  values.append(int(input())
```